# JSDOC extend/add object property in subclass

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

Consider these class and subclass:

```js
class Toolbox
{
constructor(){
/**@type {{screwdriver:()=>{},nail:()=>{}}}*/
this.contents = {screwdriver:doSomething,nail:doSomethingSomething}
}
}

///

class MyToolbox extends Toolbox
{
constructor()
{
super();
/** what do i do here in JSDoc?*/
this.contents.hammer = doSomethingElse;
}
}

class MyOtherToolbox extends Toolbox
{
constructor()
{
super();
/** what do i do here in JSDoc?*/
delete this.contents.nail;
}
}
```

In JSDoc, for MyToolbox subclass how can extend the parent 'contents' object to fit with the additional properties I just added?

Of pure curiosity, how do I account for a delete property in MyOtherToolbox subclass with JSDoc?

Also, in Toolbox base class I don't know what the subclasses will do in the future, and I don't want to keep track of that.